# Vim plugins not working with pathogen

Tags: windows, git, vim, nerdtree, pathogen

I've got a computer with windows 7 in which I've recently installed Git (with Vim inside the Git directory). I tried installed pathogen and apparently it is installed correctly since there are no error messages with pathogen in autoload. My _vimrc is located in Users/*Username* which is $HOME and it the following is relevant to pathogen.

```
execute pathogen#infect() //_vimrc starts with this line
call pathogen#helptags()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

the path to autoload and bundle is:
C:/progra~1/git/usr/share/vim/vim74/autoload(and vim74/bundle)

When I clone a plugin (ex. NerdTree) to bundle, the following message appears when I open Vim.

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim74/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim:
line   16:
E15: Invalid expression: exists("loaded_nerd_tree")^M
line  211:
E171: Missing :endif
```

I also start a session in vim and use

```
:help NERD_tree.txt
```

but it returns "Sorry, no help for NERD_tree.txt"

Does anybody know what is causing the problem and has the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**

All your configuration is supposed to happen in `$HOME/.vim/` (plugins, colorschemes, etc.) and `$HOME/.vimrc` (options, mappings, etc.). Note also that, since Vim 7.4, it is possible to have your `vimrc` directly inside `$HOME/.vim/`, which makes managing your configuration even easier.

Whatever you did in `/usr/share/vim/` should be reverted ASAP.

**Second**

But your issue is caused by line-endings: the cloning process changed the ones used by the author — `lf` — to the standard ones on Windows — `crlf`. Because Vim only accepts `lf` it was unable to source your plugin.

The cause is most likely the value of `core.autocrlf` in your Git settings.

The command below should prevent Git from converting `lf` to `crlf` upon `checkout`/`clone`/`pull`/etc.:

```
 git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Comment: Thank you! it worked.
About the usr/share/vim, that was default. When I installed Git that's how Vim came. When I installed pathogen in the autoload in that folder it worked, but when I tried with a vim folder in $HOME it didn't take it into account.

Comment: I also had the same problem with line endings. For me it was :set ff=mac on the offending nerdtree file that did the thing.

Comment: Actually it did help with vim that stopped shouting about ^M, but the plugin wasn't properly loaded. So I had to remove nerdtree and re-download with the changed autocrlf to false.